# Python nested tuples

Tags: python

Please explain the reason behind this tuple behavior.

```
>>> a=((1,(2,3)),(4,(5,6)))
>>> (1,(2,3)) in a
True
>>> a=((1,(2,3)))
>>> (1,(2,3)) in a
False
```

Comment: In your second example set `a=((1,(2,3)),)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: `(x)` does _not_ create a tuple. you must use a trailing comma `(x,)`